# Dealing with many [...] in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

In a pure ruby script I have this:

```
result = JSON.parse result.body_str
count = result && result["ke1"] && result["ke1"]["key2"] && result["ke1"]["key2"]["key3"] && result["ke1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"] ? 
        result["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"].to_i : 
        123
```

Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: Search harder, I'm certain I've seen this question over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I occasionally define a method like this

```
def value_at_deep_key hash, path, default=nil
  path.inject(hash) {|current,segment| current && current[segment]} || default
end
```

This uses inject to grab each level of the hash in turn.
You would use like this

```
value_at_deep_key(result, %w(key1 key2 key3 key4), 123)
```

Personally I don't like the use of rescue for this sort of thing - it can mask errors.

Comment: Right. Exceptions aren't for lazy flow control, they're for handling errors. Of course you have to be careful with your `||` in general, works fine if the values are numbers but not so well if `false` is a valid value.

Comment: Quite - gets a lot fiddler if you need to accommodate those cases

Comment: shouldn't it be `default: nil` instead?

Comment: and shouldn't you simplify this `path.inject({}) {|.... }` or `path.inject([]) {|...` because `hash` isn't needed there, is it?

Comment: Depends if you want to use keyword arguments or not

Comment: I think this is the same thing -> `path.inject(default) {|current,segment| current && current[segment]}`

Comment: I don't think that works - that would mean that you're calculating (first invocation of the block) default[segment]

Comment: Frederick, @7stud has demonstrated flaws in your solution. You must either fix what you have or withdraw your answer. I rarely downvote, but I will if you leave it unchanged.

Comment: It depends what you think should happen if the key path is not as expected - I'd rather it raise an exception so that I know that the data didn't match my expectations.

Comment: If you've made assumptions about the data, you need to say so in your answer.

Comment: Depending on the situation, a rescue can be far more pragmatic

Comment: This answer produces faulty results: 1)`h = {
      'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => {'key4' => 3}}}
    }
    
    p value_at_deep_key(h, %w[key1 key2 key3 key4], 123)
    
    --output:--
    3`  
2)`h = {
      'key1' => 1,
      'key2' => 2,
      'key3' => 3,
      'key4' => 4,
    }
    
    p value_at_deep_key(h, %w[key1 key2 key3 key4], 123)
    
    --output:--
    1.rb:16:in '[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

Comment: `(TypeError)
     from 1.rb:16:in 'block in value_at_deep_key'
     from 1.rb:16:in 'each'
     from 1.rb:16:in 'inject'
     from 1.rb:16:in 'value_at_deep_key'
     from 1.rb:19:in '<main>'`


3)`h = {
      'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => 4}}
    }
    
    p value_at_deep_key(h, %w[key1 key2 key3 key4], 123)
    
    --output:--
    1.rb:16:in '[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`

Comment: One of the downvotes was mine, for the reason I gave.

Answer (score 6):

```
count = result["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"].to_i rescue 123
```

if you want to make a private method for better readability, you could do

```
def count(result)
  result["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"].to_i 
rescue NoMethodError
  123
end
```

I add the NoMethodError to limit the errors that the rescue can swallow.   Despite arguments about 
using exceptions for flow control, I prefer this for readability.   In a small function or one liner, it technically doesn't even change the flow, as it all remains contained in one location.

If it is used inside a tight loop with millions of records, you may want to compare with other solutions using a profiler, but you have to make that call based on the actual usage.   If this is used on a bit of code that may run 5 times a day, stick with what's easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Your answer was needed! What are your views about including specific exceptions that would be rescued?

Comment: Can you edit your post, so I can change my downvote? I did not understand the op's code well enough when I voted.  I apologize.

Comment: Cary:  good idea, I added it to the method version to only rescue NoMethodError.   I think with the right name, the method makes it clear what the value is, and the rescue neatly provides the default value with a minimum of fuss.

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like this, and put it in a module to be included as required.

**Code**

```
def value_at_deep_key(hash, path)
  path.each_with_index.reduce(hash) do |current, (segment, i) |
    case c = current[segment]
    when Hash then c
    else (i==path.size-1) ? (current.key?(segment) ? c : :NO_MATCH) : {}
    end
  end      
end
```

**Examples**

```
value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c]) #=> "cat"
value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: false}}}, [:a, :b, :c]) #=> false
value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: nil}}},   [:a, :b, :c]) #=> nil
value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c]) #=> :NO_MATCH
value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c]) #=> :NO_MATCH
value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {z: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c]) #=> :NO_MATCH
value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b])     #=> {:c=>"cat"}
value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a])         #=> {:b=>{:c=>"cat"}}
value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [])           #=> {:z=>{:b=>{:c=>"cat"}}}
value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c]) #=> :NO_MATCH
value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c]) #=> :NO_MATCH
value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {z: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c]) #=> :NO_MATCH
value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c, :d]) #=> :NO_MATCH
```

One could then write:

```
val = value_at_deep_key(hash, path)
(val = 123) if (val == :NO_MATCH)
```

If the value for the last key could not be `nil`,

```
else (i==path.size-1) ? (current.key?(segment) ? c : :NO_MATCH) : {}
```

could be replaced with:

```
else (i==path.size-1) ? c : {}
```

in which case `nil` would be returned when there is no match.

Comment: Your code recognizes a lot of fine distinctions, which is impressive, but it changes what the original code does.  For instance, if the found value is false, then the original code will throw an error on the to_i() call.  Same with any values that are further nested Hashes.  And, neither of us has achieved the ultimate goal of the op: to simplify the original code!

Comment: @7stud, you have a valid point, but I made the assumption that this is what the Alexander wanted (though he probably wasn't worried about `nil` values), despite his code. Also, I thought this would be the sort of thing to put in a module, to be used more than once.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if the key_sequence contains 100 keys, then the op might get writer's cramp with their method.

Answer (score 0):

### The accepted answer doesn't work very well:

Here is the code:

```
def value_at_deep_key(hash, path, default=nil)
  path.inject(hash) {|current,segment| current && current[segment]} || default
end
```

Here are some results:

#### 1)--------------------

```
h = {
  'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => {'key4' => 3}}}
}

p value_at_deep_key(h, %w[key1 key2 key3 key4], 123)

--output:--
3
```

#### 2)--------------------

```
h = {
  'key1' => 1,
  'key2' => 2,
  'key3' => 3,
  'key4' => 4,
}

p value_at_deep_key(h, %w[key1 key2 key3 key4], 123)

--output:--
1.rb:16:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from 1.rb:16:in `block in value_at_deep_key'
    from 1.rb:16:in `each'
    from 1.rb:16:in `inject'
    from 1.rb:16:in `value_at_deep_key'
    from 1.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

#### 3)---------------------

```
h = {
  'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => 4}}
}

p value_at_deep_key(h, %w[key1 key2 key3 key4], 123)

--output:--
1.rb:16:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

### The following answer seems to work better:

```
def value_at_deep_key(hash, key_sequence, default=nil)
  return "No keys to lookup!" if key_sequence.empty?

  value = hash

  key_sequence.each do |key|
    case value
    when Hash
      value = value[key]
    else
      value = nil
      break
    end
  end

  value.nil? ? default : Integer(value)   #A found value of nil produces the default, which is
                                          #also the case when one of the keys doesn't exist in the Hash.
                                          #Because to_i() will silently convert a found string with no leading numbers to 0, 
                                          #use Integer() instead, which will throw a descriptive error when trying to convert any String(or Hash or Array) to an int.

end

--output:--
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "cat" (ArgumentError)
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: false}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> `Integer': can't convert false into Integer (TypeError)
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: nil}}},   [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {z: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b], 123)      #=> `Integer': can't convert Hash into Integer (TypeError
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a], 123)          #=> `Integer': can't convert Hash into Integer (TypeError)
p value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [], 123)            #=> "No keys to lookup!"
p value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {z: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c, :d], 123) #=> 123


p value_at_deep_key( 
  {'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => {'key4' => "4"}}}},
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 4

p value_at_deep_key( 
  { 'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => "4"}}},
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 123

p value_at_deep_key( 
   {
    'key1' => "1",
    'key2' => "2",
    'key3' => "3",
    'key4' => "4",
  },
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 123

p value_at_deep_key( 
  { 'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => {'key4' => nil}}}},
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 123

p value_at_deep_key( 
  {'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => {'key4' => 'hello'}}}},
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "hello" (ArgumentError)
```

### But maybe the following answer will suit you better:

If you must have:

1. A found String that looks like a number--converted to an int, or
2. The default

...in other words no errors, you can do this:

```
def value_at_deep_key(hash, key_sequence, default=nil)
  value = hash

  key_sequence.each do |key|
    case value
    when Hash
      value = value[key]
    else
      value = hash.object_id  #Some unique value to signal that the Hash lookup failed.
      break
    end
  end

  begin
    value == hash.object_id ? default : Integer(value)
  rescue TypeError, ArgumentError #If the Hash lookup succeeded, but the value is: nil, true/false, a String that is not all numbers, Array, Hash, an object that neither responds to to_int() nor to_i()
    default
  end
end

p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: false}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: nil}}},   [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {z: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b], 123)      #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a], 123)          #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [], 123)            #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({z: {b: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {b: {z: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c], 123)  #=> 123
p value_at_deep_key({a: {z: {c: "cat"}}}, [:a, :b, :c, :d], 123) #=> 123


p value_at_deep_key( 
  {'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => {'key4' => "4"}}}},
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 4

p value_at_deep_key( 
  { 'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => "4"}}},
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 123

p value_at_deep_key( 
   {
    'key1' => "1",
    'key2' => "2",
    'key3' => "3",
    'key4' => "4",
  },
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 123

p value_at_deep_key( 
  { 'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => {'key4' => nil}}}},
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 123

p value_at_deep_key( 
  {'key1' => {'key2' => {'key3' => {'key4' => [1, 2, 3] }}}},
  %w[key1 key2 key3 key4],
  default=123,
)  #=> 123
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  In that case, the op can just do: `result["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"].to_i` because that also works on #1!

Comment: It is not clear why you claim "this doesn't work" and then show a *successful* example. It's confusing.

Comment: Also this answer is not an answer (does not even attempt to answer the question) and should be removed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Which post do you think is more helpful to the op?  Mine or the accepted answer?

Comment: @Sergio, green checkmarks often leave me scratching my head.

Comment: VII, you really should have pointed out the flaws in the selected answer in a comment or comments (which you could have done, despite formatting limitations), but that's a minor point. The main thing is that reported what you found, which you were obligated to do. Consider doing that now and editing your answer to include only your solution (which probably has been largely unnoticed).