# visiting hash with keys from array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-1.8.7

I have a big hash with lots of nested key value pairs. 
Eg.

```
h = {"foo" => {"bar" => {"hello" => {"world" => "result" } } } }
```

Now I want to access `result` and I have keys for that in array in proper sequence.

```
keys_arr = ["foo", "bar", "hello", "world"]
```

The motive is clear, I want to do following:

```
h["foo"]["bar"]["hello"]["world"]
# => "result"
```

But I don't know how to do this. I am currently doing:

```
key = '["' +  keys_arr.join('"]["') + '"]'
eval("h"+key)
# => "result"
```

Which looks like a hack. Also it greatly reduces my ability to work with hash in real environment.

Please suggest alternate and better ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (or [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)):

```
h = {"foo" => {"bar" => {"hello" => {"world" => "result" } } } }
keys_arr = ["foo", "bar", "hello", "world"]
keys_arr.inject(h) { |x, k| x[k] }
# => "result"
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to do something like: `h["foo"]["bar"]["hello"]["world"] = "ruby"`

```
innermost = keys_arr[0...-1].inject(h) { |x, k| x[k] } # the innermost hash
innermost[keys_arr[-1]] = "ruby"
```

Comment: wow.. its so easy!! And i assumed i was asking a fairly tricky question. :P

Comment: two issues: 1> I am still not accessing it as `h["foo"]["bar"]["hello"]["world"]` so if I want to manipulate the hash I wont be able to do so. 2> It is manipulating the original hash which is not a desired thing.

Comment: @shivam, What do you mean it is manipulating the original hash? It does not unless you use older version of Ruby. If that's the case use other name for instead of `h` in the block: `keys_arr.inject(h) { |x, k| x[k] }`

Comment: @shivam, For the first issue, try this: `innermost = keys_arr[0...-1].inject(h) { |x, k| x[k] };
innermost[keys_arr[-1]] = "ruby"`  (`innermost` will reference the innermost hash object)

Comment: yeah you were right. I am using ruby 1.8.7 and changing the name to `x` did solve the issue. thanks

Comment: @shivam, I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

```
keys_arr.inject(h, :[])
```

will do

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
h = {"foo" => {"bar" => {"hello" => {"world" => 10 } } } }
keys = ["foo", "bar", "hello", "world"]

result = h

keys.each do |key|
  result = result[key]
end

puts result  #=>10
```

If the key may not exist, see here:

[Dealing with many [...] in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594719/dealing-with-many-in-ruby/25595437?noredirect=1#comment39982453_25595437)